# Customize Survey fields in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a Survey list which has several questions, one of those is people picker field and the another one is single line of text field.

I need to hide a perticular question ( field ) based on login user. Requirement is as below

1. When the user logs in as admin

   a. Display ‘people picker’ and should not allow user to pick his name from people picker.

   b. Hide Single line of Text field.
2. When the user logs in as ‘Non-Admin’

   a. Display ‘Single line of Text' field and default it to have the logged in user name (without domain name).

   b. Hide ‘People picker’ control.

I am thinking that we can do it by placing javascript in content editor webpart and add it in newform.apx of survey list. Can anybody give me the proper approach to get it done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are trying to work around an issue where you have people logging on with specific domain accounts for admin access (e.g. barney_admin) correct?

Comment: @ Nat - Yes. Admin as well as non-admin people can login to my site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to try creating a [custom field control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd727508.aspx), a differnet one for each field.

Javascript is fast and involves minimal deployment, but is fiddly and can be turned off.